# Jquery $(function(){}), what does it mean?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

In Jquery, I understand that

```
$()
```

is there to select an element and when you do something like

`$(".foo").click(function(){})`

will execute function when foo class is clicked..

but when you do,

```
$(function(){})
```

does this mean you are selecting a function? it doesn't seem right to me..

Comment: it's shorthand for the $(document).on('ready', function());

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10595913/jquery-function-and-document-ready-the-same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's just a shortcut for

```
$(document).ready(function() {});
```

which will be called when the DOM ready event fires

See the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) for `.ready`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){})
```

This will be your function that need to be called.